# Angular 2 datapicker Disabled

Tags: datepicker, angular2-forms

I have written an angular code, here based on select tag yes or no. I need to change the text box having date-picker to be enable disable. But its not working.

Here is my code..,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Signed AOB</label>
            <select name="signed" class="form-control required" [(ngModel)]="signed" (change)="checkSigned(signed)">
                <option value="N">No</option>
                <option value="Y">Yes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date</label>
            <input type="text" name="Date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="Date" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY" datepicker disabled="isEnabled">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and corresponding component..,

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  templateUrl: './app/components/tab/tab.component.html'
})

export class TabComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(){}

    @Input() tab: Object;    

    checkSigned(value){
        if(value === 'Y'){
            this.isEnabled=true;
        }else{
            this.isEnabled=false;
        }
    }

    ngOnInit(){

    }

}
```

datepicker directive..,,

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";

declare var $: any;

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_DATE_PICKER_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatePicker),
    multi: true
};

@Directive({
    selector: '[datepicker]',
    host: { '(blur)': 'onTouched($event)' },
    providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_DATE_PICKER_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class DatePicker implements ControlValueAccessor {
    private innerValue: string;

    @Input('changeMonth') changeMonth: boolean = true;
    @Input('changeYear') changeYear: boolean = true;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        $(this.el.nativeElement).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
        }).on('change', (e: any) => {
            this.onChange(e.target.value);
        });
    }


    public onChange: any = (_:any) => {  }
    public onTouched: any = () => {  }

    get value(): any {
        return this.innerValue;
    };

    set value(v: any) {
        if (v !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = v;
            this.onChange(v);
        }
    }


    writeValue(val: string): void {
        this.innerValue = val;
        $(this.el.nativeElement).datepicker("setDate", this.innerValue);
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the prb by adding this in directive,

```
setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', isDisabled);
    }
```

Thanks all for your help:-)

Answer (score 0):

It is becuase your `ngModel` got updated only after your change function got triggerd. so please your change `checkSigned()` function as below

```
<select name="signed" class="form-control required" [(ngModel)]="signed" (change)="checkSigned($event.target.value)">
    <option value="N">No</option>
    <option value="Y">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanq for updated sainu, I updated my code as u told. but if i change select drop down as "no" also it disabled,i donno what is the problem.

Comment: please change disabled="isEnabled" to [disabled]="isEnabled"

Comment: sainu.., it was working fine for text box alone, i having datapicker in that, so only its not working for me

Comment: which datepicker are you using? there will be some properties for disabling it based on some conditions. can you please mention the datepicker you are using and its version?

Comment: i used separate directive for it, i have edited above ques pls check it... thanq

Comment: please try this, I don't know whether it work or not

`<input type="text" name="Date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="Date" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY" [datepicker]="isEnabled" disabled="isEnabled">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143741/discussion-between-jay-and-sainu).

Comment: I searched a lot to add your directive conditionally but I didn't find any solution
I think you can add one more input and hide and show like this:
`<input type="text" name="Date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="Date" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY" datepicker *ngIf="!isEnabled">
<input type="text" value={{Date}} *ngIf="isEnabled">`